# How to Change the App Name on a Crashlytics Beta Email Invite

Tags: ios, xcode7, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-beta

In Crashlytics Beta does anyone know how to change the app name (under the app icon) on the email invite. My iOS distribution is coming from a Xcode 7 archive via the Twitter Fabric menubar on MacOS. The Xcode project is called something like *someprototype* and I'd like to make it more presentable for testers. I've changed the bundle name and archive name but neither of these have any effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here.

Check out how to change your app's [name here](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/fabric/manage-your-settings/app.html#renaming-your-app). Once you save that new name, it will take affect for any new invites or notifications:

> Note: You must be an Admin in your organization to update an app’s name.
>
> To
> rename your app, head to your app’s settings then select the app whose
> name you want to change and click on the edit button to the left of
> the current name. Make your changes and then click on the blue
> checkmark to save them.

Comment: This answer is correct; just for clarity the option is available from the fabric.io dashboard for a users projects, i.e. in the settings at the top right hand corner under the users name. To me this looked like user profile settings, but there's other stuff there too including app settings. Also a note just to underline that this stuff is in the fabric.io web app rather than the MacOS Fabric menubar item.