# Fabric / Crashlytics delete organisation catch 22

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am using Crashlytics (Fabric) for distrubution of one of my iOS apps. I want to rename an organization and its apps, but that it doesn't seam possible to do that.

The solution appears to be to delete the old organization, create a new one and add the app to it.

However, there is a real catch 22 here, in order to delete an organization in Fabric, it has to have zero apps. Twitter staff person @mike-bonnell [says](https://twittercommunity.com/t/delete-organization/48801/4):

> If you need to remove an organization, you need to be an admin and have no apps in that organization. Then head to fabric.io/settings/organizations609, select your organization and then click on the "Delete Organization" button in the top-right corner.

It is now it becomes a real catch 22, when I try to delete my *only* app in the organization I wish to delete, I get an error message saying;

> Oops!
>   Can't delete your last app

[image]

So.. well... that sucks... What to do?

And no, I do not just want to [rename the app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32630842/1311272), I want to rename the organization (and add an app with a new name to this new organization).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

If you want to remove your current organization, first you would need to create the new organization and add an app to it. Then you could remove the old app and organization.

However, if you're only looking to [rename the organization's name](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/settings/organization.html#rename-organization), you can do that from your organization's settings page on Fabric. Select the organization, then click the pencil icon next to the current name and enter the new name. Press Enter to save or click on the blue checkmark.

Comment: Thanks mike! I actually successfully removed the organization yesterday. Because I was able to add a app to the new organsation.

Comment: Maybe Fabric can improve its Readme regarding this issue, and also, isn't it strange that I have to create a new organization just to be able to delete another organization?

Comment: Glad you're all set @Sajjon and yes, it is a bit confusing and a part of our UX that I'd like to see improved.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Well, if you create an organization by mistake then it's impossible to remove it. I don't have an app to add to it and I don't want to add an app to it. I just want to remove the organization.

Comment: If this happens and you're unable to remove the organization, then contacting support(at)fabric(dot)io is the best way to go to get help.

Answer (score 2):

This is still an issue and the documentation is still not helpful either, even after the Google acquisition.

- > To remove an organization, head to your app’s settings. Then **remove
  >   all existing apps in the organization** by following the steps here.
  >   After removing all apps and confirming the organization’s deletion,
  >   the organization will be removed and no one will be able to access it.
- > You must be an Admin in your organization to remove an app. Also, **your organization must have at least 2 apps to remove one.**

However, I found a solution while I was cleaning up my old organizations.

1. If you have only one app, add another app.
2. Go to organization settings and open the details of all of the apps in separate tabs
3. Delete all the apps using those separate tabs.

To me it seems like not letting the user delete the last app is just an arbitrary restriction.

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to delete an organization that doesn't have apps. There's a link on the top right corner to delete it.